# extract all the strings between two characters powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Following are the two characters.
 1. {{
 2. }}
I'm trying to find all the strings between these characters in the following file.

```
    <add key="CSDFG_SqlServerFailOverInterval" value="{{environment}}"/>
    <add key="CSDFG_JobResetInterval" value="600000"/>
    <add key="FileTypeFilter" value="{{filetype}}"/>
```

and I'm using following powershell commands,

```
$x = C:\app.config
$s = Get-Content $x
$prog = [regex]::match($s,'{{([^/)]+)}}').Groups[1].Value
write-host $prog
```

and my output is just one string. it is not pulling all the strings. Can someone please suggest me how to get the all the strings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[regex]::Match()` only returns the *first* match. Use `[regex]::Matches()` to capture all matches:

```
$s = Get-Content 'C:\app.config'
[regex]::Matches($s, '{{([^/)]+)}}') |ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: Great. It is working as expected. Thanks a lot Mathias.

Comment: Actually the app.config file also includes following data.
<!-- CompareServices Installer Specific -->
    <add key="ServicesToRun" value="CompareServices.{{servicename}},CompareServices.{{servicename}}~Compare{{servicename}}{{serviceinstance}}" />

When I'm running the command to find out the strings, it is showing like as follows,
servicename}},CompareServices.{{servicename}}~Compare{{servicename}}{{serviceinstance

Please suggest me how can I pull just strings, not whole sentense.

Comment: `{{([^/)]+?)}}` Use a non-greedy quantifier\

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.